# How to check version number greater or lower

Tags: php

How to check if a version number is greater or lower than another version number. Is their any tiny library for this?

Example:

```
'1.1.2' > '1.1.10' // should return false
'1.1.10' > '1.1.9' // should return true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP function `version_compare` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)).

Then you can check what value returned (part of official documentation):

> By default, version_compare() returns -1 if the first version is lower
>   than the second, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the second is lower.